# parsing and formatting Date and Time in Java

Tags: java, datetime

on one site which i want to grab, i have a format date and time like this:

```
<div id="date">11 october 2010 <span>|</span> 21:43</div>
```

at first i want to split the time and date in two variables, and after this push it to my table in my mysql.

as well as i need to change the format date in smth like this: `2013-05-10`

now i have only this:

```
String date = (driver.findElement(By.id("date"))).getText();
```

how can i split and change format of this?

Comment: You want to change the format of the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the date string contains something like "11 october 2010 | 21:43". You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for this. In your case this should work:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatIn =
        new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy '|' HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatOut =
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

String dateStr = (driver.findElement(By.id("date"))).getText();
Date date = simpleDateFormatIn.parse(dateStr);

System.out.println(simpleDateFormatOut.format(date));
```

A nice little blog about this can be found [here](http://www.javablogging.com/java-simpledateformat-examples/):